# Detect fullscreen mode switch without manual checking every second

Tags: windows, winapi, window-messages

I have a topmost window. I need it be the topmost over any other topmost window but not cover any fullscreen window:
particularly: {Windows Media Player, Youtube flash player, RDP}

There is a solution with continuous checks:

- every YYY milliseconds I check is there(on the same display) another topmost window with dimensions equal to screen dimensions.
- if so: make my window non-topmost, otherwise make it topmost.

But I’m looking for another less resource-consuming solution which will not perform dozens of system calls and traverse the entire tree of topmost windows every second.

I can handle any WM_

I can inject hook into a process.

The problem:

How to detect a full screen window on the same desktop?

How to detect fullscreen mode using incoming WM_(s) or any technique other than continuous checking?

Comment: "I need it be the topmost over any other topmost window..." Imagine if two programs did this. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/03/10/10138969.aspx

Comment: topmost -- is not the problem;
The problem: how to detect full screen window(s), particularly Youtube flash player which is not a topmost window but toolwindow.

Comment: I know that (which is why it's a comment and not an answer).  I'm just saying that having a goal of trying to be the topmost window over all other topmost windows is foolhardy.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [`SetWindowsHookEx()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to set a CBT hook (WH_CBT). In particular, in your [`CBTProc()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644977%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) you'll get a `WHCBT_MOVESIZE` notification when a window is being moved or sized.